# Add bounds to constraint´s indexes in AMPL

Tags: optimization, ampl

I am trying to solve a chess board optimisation problem and one of my constraints checks if cells nearby are occupied or not:

```
subject to attack_each_cell {i in 1..n,j in 1..n}:

    P[i,j]+P[i-1,j+2]+P[i-1,j-2]+P[i+1,j+2]+P[i+1,j-2]+P[i-2,j+1]+P[i-2,j-1]+P[i+2,j+1]+P[i+2,j-1]>=1
```

The problem with the constraint above is that for border cells I get an out of bounds error, so my second approach was an if-else statement on (i,j) indexes:

```
P[i,j]
+ if i>1   and j<n-2 then P[i-1,j+2] 
+ if i>1   and j>2   then P[i-1,j-2] 
+ if i<n-1 and j<n-2 then P[i+1,j+2] 
+ if i<n-1 and j>2   then P[i+1,j-2] 
+ if i>2   and j<n-1 then P[i-2,j+1] 
+ if i>2   and j>1   then P[i-2,j-1] 
+ if i<n-2 and j<n-1 then P[i+2,j+1] 
+ if i<n-2 and j>1   then P[i+2,j-1]
>=1
```

This is not working because it appears the statements are being nested instead of executed in sequence. Any suggestion on how to fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: add brackets to fix order of evaluation.

Option 2: reformulate your constraint. Instead of checking knight-move positions relative to the reference cell and then having to deal with the out-of-bounds case, check all positions on the board and accept the ones that are a knight's move from the reference cell:

```
subject to attack_each_cell {i in 1..n,j in 1..n}: 
  P[i,j] 
+ sum{i1 in 1..n, j1 in 1..n: abs(i-i1) = 2 and abs(j-j1) = 1} P[i1,j1]
+ sum{i1 in 1..n, j1 in 1..n: abs(i-i1) = 1 and abs(j-j1) = 2} P[i1,j1]
>= 1;
```

Option 3: as above, but start by creating a set that defines legitimate moves, and then define the constraint by referring to that set:

```
set KnightMoves := {(i,j) in 
  ({-1,1} cross {-2,2})
  union 
  ({-2,2} cross {-1,1})
  }; # this defines the set of moves {(-1,-2),(-1,2), ... (2,1)}

subject to attack_each_cell {i in 1..n,j in 1..n}: 
  P[i,j] + sum{i1 in 1..n, j1 in 1..n: (i-i1,j-j1) in KnightMoves} P[i1,j1]
>= 1;
```

I like #3 best because it splits out the logic "how knights move" from the constraint "any cell that doesn't contain a knight must be threatened by a knight". This makes it a bit easier to customise, e.g. if you need to solve the problem for a different kind of piece, and it extends neatly to problems with more than one type of piece:

```
subject to attack_each_cell {i in 1..n,j in 1..n}: 
  P[i,j] 
+ sum{i1 in 1..n, j1 in 1..n: (i-i1,j-j1) in KnightMoves} Knights[i1,j1]
+ sum{i1 in 1..n, j1 in 1..n: (i-i1,j-j1) in BishopMoves} Bishops[i1,j1]
+ sum{i1 in 1..n, j1 in 1..n: (i-i1,j-j1) in Pawn} Pawns[i1,j1]
+ ...
>= 1;
```

(edit: well, it does if you ignore the issue of non-jumping pieces being blocked by others.)

Comment: Option 1 worked perfectly, and the other two are very elegant and scalable. Thanks!

Comment: @BenjamínBarros "add more brackets" is right after "check the semicolons" on my debugging checklist ;-) If you're happy with that answer, don't forget to flag it as answered so other posters know they don't need to help.